# Distance between two cities in php

Tags: php, javascript

I want to display events occuring near my city from the database.I tried to calculate the distance between the given city and my city using Google distance API. But the problem is that the distance is in javascript and I have to compare this with some integer to determmine whether to list the event or not and repeat this process for each event. Is there any way to pass value from javascript to php other than ajax or any other method to calculate the distance between two cities?

Comment: javascript can't communicate directly with php once the page has been rendered. This means that any data you need to send to the server for processing has to be done with ajax, a fake iframe, or regular form submission.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, that is not entirely true. You can use NodeJS or PhantomJS to run JavaScript server-side: http://phantomjs.org/ http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Make an attempt.  Show us some code, and we'll try to help you debug it.

Comment: I don't see what the problem with using AJAX is.. All you need to do is pass a query string with the given variable.

Comment: @Set Sail Media Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you want to pass data from a user event between node.js and the client , it still requires an open HTTPD connection, does it not?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, correct, in most cases it does. But you can also use PHP's `exec()` to initiate and retrieve JavaScript data from within a PHP thread.

Comment: @Set Sail Media fair enough. have a nice day.

Comment: @ChrisCooney The problem with ajax is that i already have a php array with the events  and I have to calculate distance for each element in this array and if near to my city, add to another array.How to do that using ajax? Use ajax for each array element and add to second array if near to my city in php?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you can't just download it from your server directly and parse json.

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=bicycling&sensor=false");
$json=json_decode($json,true);
$distance=$json["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"];
echo $distance;
```

This displays 1677606, you can read up on the google distance [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#RequestParameters).

You can also print_r on $json to see the structure of the response.